# Spring boot security for standalone rest services

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Let's say I'm building a Spring Boot REST service which has endpoints

```
/users/myself
/users/myself/books
```

and I have users and books stored in the DB.

Of course you need to be authenticated to access these resources, but whenever I search for "Spring Rest security" it gives you basically three options

1. Basic Auth
2. OAuth2
3. JWT tokens

And you barely see anyone proposing using sessions for authentication, which doesn't make sense to me, especially in small standalone services. And here is why:

1. Basic auth is never good idea for authentication, because that would require storing username:password in some storage to keep user authenticated.
2. OAuth2 seems to be unusable for this use case where we don't have a dedicated authorization server. And having a built-in authorization server in a spring boot app seems an overkill to me and serves no advantage over sessions.
3. If you really create a stateless JWT token, then that brings a ton of security issues - not able to revoke the token. If you keep a list of tokens in DB then it's no longer a stateless REST service and essentially acts like sessions, except you have to build ton of custom logic to make it work while session handling comes OOTB in Spring.

So why the heck not use sessions for authentication?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [security for web applications session vs token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490092/security-for-web-applications-session-vs-token)

Answer (score 0):

Often the motivation is around security for your API's clients and how they connect with your API. Especially when they are public clients, where modern security can be a hot topic.

- Browser UIs
- Mobile UIs

OAuth tech can potentially simplify and externalise your security, as in my [initial tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/), where there is almost zero security code in either UI or API. The API is stateless and state is externalised to a low cost and highly available Cloud Authorization Server.

With the right designs, tokens are short lived (with no need for revocation) and the code you write will be much simpler than when you use sessions. It will support modern hosting in clustered environments and be more portable.

Architecturally there are quite a few other benefits - though you are right that there are technical challenges. So it is often a case of choosing the time for this kind of leap and agreeing it with your stakeholders.